# Veewee Install Error

Tags: ruby, virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant, veewee

I'm trying to install veewee for vagrant, so that I may take advantage of the automation it employs to create base boxes.  I could be doing something wrong, but I don't think so...

Here's what I'm running:

```
gem install veewee
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: vagrant requires json (~> 1.5.1)
```

I also tried the following:

```
sudo gem install veewee
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: cucumber requires json (>= 1.4.6); gherkin requires json (>= 1.7.6); vagrant requires json (~> 1.5.1)
```

Comment: have you tried installing the json gem?

Comment: I think I have 1.7.7 installed, as when I did gem update and it said `Successfully installed json-1.7.7`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to vagrant requiring an old version of json (for compatibility with windows, say the developers) while gherkin recently started requiring some newer one. To solve it, you should:

1. Make sure you remove any previously installed json gem:

   `gem uninstall json`
2. Install vagrant first, so that it downloads the old json:

   `gem install vagrant`
3. Install an old gherkin gem:

   `gem install gherkin --version '2.11.5'`
4. Now you can install veewee:

   `gem install veewee`

I went through this issue today and this is the sequence that worked for me. Reference:
https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/issues/518

I hope it helps you.

Best regards,

Ricardo.

Comment: I'll give this a go!  Thanks Ricardo!  I used the Mac OSX installer to install Vagrant.  Would that have something to do with it?  Is it preferable to use the installer as upposed to a gem?

Comment: Hey there Ricardo!  I have confirmed that this works, however, I'm going to wait a couple days for Vagrant 1.0.7 to come out, as it fixes this issue apparently.